proving the equation $x^4-3y^4=z^2$ has no positive integer solutions
I want to prove that $x^4-3y^4=z^2$ has no solution in positive integers. Here is what I do:
Firstly, $y$ must be even otherwise $z^2 \equiv 5 $ or $6 \mod 8$, which is impossible, and since we are seeking primitive solution $(x,y)=1$, therefore $x,z$ odd. Now write the equation as:
$$(x^2+z)(x^2-z)=3y^4$$
divide both side by 4 we obtain:
$$\frac{x^2+z}{2} \frac{x^2-z}{2} = 3 \left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right)^2$$
and i want to use the theorem:

If u and v are relatively prime positive integers whose product uv is a perfect square, then u and v are both perfect squares.

But I am stuck here. Is there any suggestion?

+1: nicely presented, with nice work shown.  In a situation like this, I would try to metacheat.  That is, if the problem is from a book or class, then the problem composer (perhaps) intends that the exercise use recent previous results (e.g. previously solved problems, worked examples, theorems).  Besides the work that you have done so far, what other recent results do you think might be relevant?

see pages 23 and 24 in Mordell, Diophantine Equations.

Note that, as Bill's comment suggests, the solution method I use in my answer is fairly similar to what shown in the book pages that Will's comment above indicates.

@user2661923 this question was asked in exercises in Baker's number theory. Original question is:
Prove that the equation $x^4 -3y^4 = z^2$ has no solution in
positive integers x, y, z. Deduce that the equation $x^4 +
y^4 = z^3$ has no such solution with (x, y) = 1.

You've made a good start with the equation of
$$x^4 - 3y^4 = z^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
Assume there is at least one solution in positive integers, and then choose among the one or more of them where $y$ has the minimum possible value. Also, instead of dividing by $4$, consider instead that with $y$ being even, we have
$$(x^2 + z)(x^2 - z) = 3(2^4)\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^4 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
Since $x$ and $z$ are odd, and we're looking for primitive solutions so $\gcd(x, z) = 1$, we have
$$\gcd(x^2 + z, x^2 - z) = \gcd(x^2 + z, 2z) = 2 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$
Thus, one of those of factors has just one factor of $2$, with the other one having at least $3$ factors of $2$, plus exactly one of those two factors must also have a factor of $3$. Using this, along with the theorem you mentioned which also applies to fourth powers, there are $4$ cases to consider where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, with $ab = \frac{y}{2}$ and $a$ being odd,
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x^2 + z = 2a^4, & \;\; x^2 - z = 24b^4 \;\;\to\;\; x^2 = a^4 + 12b^4 \\
x^2 + z = 6a^4, & \;\; x^2 - z = 8b^4 \;\;\to\;\; x^2 = 3a^4 + 4b^4  \\
x^2 + z = 24b^4, & \;\; x^2 - z = 2a^4 \;\;\to\;\; x^2 = a^4 + 12b^4 \\
x^2 + z = 8b^4, & \;\; x^2 - z = 6a^4 \;\;\to\;\; x^2 = 3a^4 + 4b^4 \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$
Since $a$ is odd, then $a^4\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, so the second and fourth cases have $x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, which is not possible. Thus, we only then have the first and third case results, i.e.,
$$x^2 = a^4 + 12b^4 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$
Since $x^2 \equiv a^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$, then $12b^4 \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$, i.e., $b$ is even. This means \eqref{eq5A} becomes
$$(x + a^2)(x - a^2) = 3(2^6)\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^2 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$
Similar to how \eqref{eq2A} was handled, there are once again $4$ cases to consider where $c$ and $d$ are positive integers, with $cd = \frac{b}{2}$ and $c$ being odd,
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x + a^2 = 2c^4, & \;\; x - a^2 = 96d^4 \;\;\to\;\; a^2 = c^4 - 48d^4 \\
x + a^2 = 6c^4, & \;\; x - a^2 = 32d^4 \;\;\to\;\; a^2 = 3c^4 - 16d^4  \\
x + a^2 = 96d^4, & \;\; x - a^2 = 2c^4 \;\;\to\;\; a^2 = 48d^4 - c^4 \\
x + a^2 = 32d^4, & \;\; x - a^2 = 6c^4 \;\;\to\;\; a^2 = 16d^4 - 3c^4  \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$
Checking modulo $8$ shows only the first case is possible, i.e., we get
$$c^4 - 48d^4 = a^2 \;\;\to\;\; c^4 - 3(2d)^4 = a^2 \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$
Note this is in the same form as \eqref{eq1A}, so since $y$ there was chosen to be the smallest positive integer where a solution exists, we must therefore have
$$2d \ge y \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$
From the first case of \eqref{eq7A}, since $c \ge 3$, we get from \eqref{eq6A} that
$$d \le \frac{b}{2(3)} \;\;\to\;\; 2d \le \frac{b}{3} \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$
Next, from \eqref{eq4A} and \eqref{eq2A}, and using \eqref{eq10A}, we have
$$b \le \frac{y}{2} \;\;\to\;\; 2d \le \frac{y}{6} \tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$
However, this contradicts \eqref{eq9A}, which means the original assumption of there being at least one solution in positive integers of \eqref{eq1A} cannot be true.

At first glance this appears to be essentially the same descent method used by Mordell and inked in Jagy's prior comment in the question. If that is so then it would be useful to confirm it so that readers needn't waste time reading both.

@BillDubuque I came up with my solution and was writing it before Jagy's prior comment appeared. Nonetheless, based on what's shown in the Google book version, on page #$24$, it is similar to what I did, although I do provide a few more details. ...

@BillDubuque (cont.) To help avoid people looking at both my solution and also what's in that book who would prefer not to, I've also just posted a comment to the question indicating the similarity.

►$x$ even and $y$ odd implies $0-3\equiv z^2\pmod{16}$.
►$x$ and $y$ odd implies $1-3=-2\equiv z^2\pmod{16}$
Since $\left(\mathbb Z/16\mathbb Z\right)^2=\{1,4,9,0\}$, the two equations above have no solutions.
►$x$  and $y$ even implies $0-0\equiv z^2\pmod{16}$ so $z=16z_1$.
►$x$ odd, $y$ even implies $1-0\equiv z^2\pmod{16}$ so $z\equiv 1,7,15\pmod{16}$ because for $z\equiv 3,5,9,11,13\pmod{16}$ one has $z^2=9$ in $\left(\mathbb Z/16\mathbb Z\right)^2$.
Therefore one has to solve the following equations
$$(2x)^4-3(2y)^4=16^2z^2................. (1)\\(2x+1)^4-3(2y)^4=(16z+7)^2.........(2)\\(2x+1)^4-3(2y)^4=(16z\pm1)^2.........(3)$$
For $(1)$  we have $$16x^4-3\times 16y^4=16^2z^2\implies x^4-3y^4=16z^2\implies x\text{ and } y \text{ even}$$ which leads to $x_1^4-3y_1^4=z^2$ so by descent we are done.
It remains to solve $(2)$ and $(3)$.
$$(2x+1)^4-3(2y)^4=(16z+7)^2.........(2)\\(2x+1)^4-3(2y)^4=(16z\pm1)^2.........(3)$$
For $(2)$, putting $X=\dfrac{(2x+1)^2}{16z+7}$ and $Y=\dfrac{4y^2}{16z+7}$ we get the equation $X^2-3Y^2=1$ whose integer solutions are given by
$$X_n=\mp\frac{(2-\sqrt3)^n+(2+\sqrt3)^n}{2}\\Y_n=\pm\frac{(2-\sqrt3)^n-(2+\sqrt3)^n}{2}$$ for all $n\ge0$. It follows for $n=1$ $$(2x_1+1)^2=\mp2(16z_1+7)$$ which is impossible (because it gives odd=even).
Similarly for $(3)$ we get  $$(2x_1+1)^2=\mp2(16z_1\pm1)$$ what ends the proof.

Inspired by other answers, I finished my proof. Here it is:
Firstly, if there is a solution then $y$ must be even otherwise $z^2 \equiv 5 $ or $6 \mod 8$, which is impossible, and since we are seeking primitive solutions $(x,y)=1$, therefore $x,z$ odd. Now write the equation as:
$$(x^2+z)(x^2-z)=3y^4$$
divide both side by 4 we obtain:
$$(\frac{x^2+z}{2})( \frac{x^2-z}{2}) = 3 \left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right)^2$$
Also we have $(x^2+z , x^2 - z) = ( x^2 + z , 2z) = 2$. Therefore the factors on the left side are relatively prime. Since $3$ divides the product, it must divide one of them.
If $3$ divides $\frac{x^2-z}{2}$ then for some relatively prime and positive integers $r,s$  we have:
$$\frac{x^2+z}{2}=r^2 \text{  and  } \frac{x^2-z}{6}= s^2 \implies x^2=r^2+3s^2 \text{ and } y^2=2rs$$
If $3$ divides $\frac{x^2+z}{2}$ then for some relatively prime and positive integers $r',s'$ we have:
$$\frac{x^2+z}{6}=r'^2 \text{  and  } \frac{x^2-z}{2}= s'^2 \implies x^2=3r'^2+s'^2 \text{ and } y^2=2r's'$$
But the equations in both cases are in the same format. So we can continue from the first one, i.e. $$x^2=r^2+3s^2 \text{ and } y^2=2rs$$
Now, let us examine the equation $x^2=r^2+3s^2 $.
Since $x$ is odd, one of  $r,s$ must be even and the other is odd. However, if $r$ is even then $x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{4} $, which is impossible. Hence $s$ is even and $r$ is odd. Now write the last equation as:
$$(\frac{x-r}{2})(\frac{x+r}{2}) = 3 \left(\frac{s}{2}\right)^2 $$
Clearly factors on the left side are relatively prime and $3$ divides one of them. Applying the same procedure as above, we have two cases:
$$r = \pm (a^2 -3 b^2) \text{ and } s = 2ab \text{ where } a,b \text{ positive integers and } (a,b)=1$$
Since $r$ is odd,  $a,b $ have opposite parity.
Writing what we find in the equation $y^2 = 2rs$, we have:
$$ y^2 = \pm4ab(a^2 - 3b^2)$$
Factors on the right hand side are pairwise relatively prime, so for some $\alpha, \beta , \theta $ positive integers we have:
$a = \alpha^2 , b=\beta^2$ and $a^2 - 3b^2 = \pm \theta^2 \implies \alpha^4 - 3\beta^4 = \pm \theta^2 $ .
Since  $a,b $ have opposite parity, $\alpha, \beta$  are opposite parity also.
But then if $\alpha^4 - 3\beta^4 = -\theta^2 \implies \theta^2 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ which is impossible.
Hence,  $$\alpha^4 - 3\beta^4 = \theta^2$$ this is in the same format as our original equation and clearly the solutions $(\alpha , \beta)$ are smaller than the solutions $ (x,y)$. Thus, there is no least solution for this equation and therefore there is no solutions in positive integers.
